# decltype in class template specialization

Tags: c++, c++11, template-specialization, decltype

I am trying to use decltype inside a template class as follows:

```
#include <functional>
template <typename T>
class A
{
    typedef decltype(std::bind(&A::f, std::declval<A>())) some_type;

    void f();
};
```

That works fine, but now I'd like to add an explicit specialization:

```
template <>
class A<void>
{
    typedef decltype(std::bind(&A::f, std::declval<A>())) some_type;

    void f();
};
```

This time g++ gives an error:

```
test.cpp:14:33: error: incomplete type 'A<void>' used in nested name specifier
```

What am I doing wrong? I am using gcc 4.5.

EDIT: If I move the declaration of `void f();` to above the typedef, as suggested by Johannes, I get (slightly) different errors:

```
test.cpp:15:62: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class A<void>'
test.cpp:13:1: error: declaration of 'class A<void>'
test.cpp:15:62: error:   initializing argument 2 of 'std::_Bind<typename std::_Maybe_wrap_member_pointer<_Tp>::type(_ArgTypes ...)> std::bind(_Functor, _ArgTypes ...) [with _Functor = void (A<void>::*)(), _ArgTypes = {A<void>}, typename std::_Maybe_wrap_member_pointer<_Tp>::type = std::_Mem_fn<void (A<void>::*)()>]'
test.cpp:15:62: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class A<void>'
test.cpp:13:1: error: declaration of 'class A<void>'
test.cpp:15:62: error:   initializing argument 2 of 'std::_Bind<typename std::_Maybe_wrap_member_pointer<_Tp>::type(_ArgTypes ...)> std::bind(_Functor, _ArgTypes ...) [with _Functor = void (A<void>::*)(), _ArgTypes = {A<void>}, typename std::_Maybe_wrap_member_pointer<_Tp>::type = std::_Mem_fn<void (A<void>::*)()>]'
```

Comment: "A Void" is an incomplete *typography*, lacking as it does the letter "e". (Too obscure? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Void)

Comment: @Steve LOL... if only humour made code compile...

Comment: yes, sorry I can't actually help with the question.

Comment: Here is another code showing the same issue, this time with no templates at all, hope it will help: http://ideone.com/iTyPg

Comment: You may already have won a g++ bug! Clang accepts your code, once the declaration order is fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your order is wrong. Try exchanging it

```
template <>
class A<void>
{    
    void f();
    typedef decltype(std::bind(&A::f, std::declval<A>())) some_type;
};
```

In the primary template, the name `A::f` was dependent and the compiler delayed lookup to a point where `f` was declared (`A::f` is not really dependent in C++0x anymore, since `A` refers to the current instantiation and therefor `f` to a member of the current instantiation, but as there is a loophole in the current specification (it has to do with dependent base classes), the compiler delayed the lookup nontheless). In the explicit specialization, the name is not dependent and lookup is done immediately, which is the reason you need to declare `f` before referring to it.

**Edit:** You are wrongly using `std::bind`. The second argument you give is of type `A<void>`, which will be copied/moved by `std::bind` into its created call wrapper object. This requires a complete type `A<void>`.

If you want to merely pass a reference to `A` on which the member function is called, you can pass a `declval<A*>()`, which the `std::bind` mechanism equally detects as magical first argument to a member pointer invocation.

But it seems to me you want to look into `std::function<>`, instead of doing this `std::bind` and `decltype` mess. After all you have a powerful toolset given, but by using this doubtful `decltype` expression, you throw away all the genericity the Standard library gives you and restrict yourself to use of that single `std::bind` expression. That's no good.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem, but the errors do become slightly different (see edit to question)

Comment: OK. I think I get it know. Johannes is correct, and after solving this issue another issue is revealed. My experiment with VS 2010 does not show this problem, probably because VS does not implement two phase lookup, therefore only the second problem is shown.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Why is A<void> being incomplete not a problem when I put the typedef inside a member function with an inline definition?

Comment: As for std::function<>, my understanding is that it comes at a cost of a virtual function call per invocation. I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: @HighCommander4 within member functions, default arguments and the constructor initializer list, the class is regarded as complete, so that you can access all its members and create objects of its type inside them.

Answer (score 2):

std::bind requires A as a complete type (see answer by Johannes) and therefore you cannot use it at this point. As a workaround, if you encapsulate the some_type this [will compile](http://ideone.com/NaATq):

```
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
class A
{
  void f();
  struct some_type_helper
  {
    typedef decltype(std::bind(&A::f, std::declval<A>())) some_type;
  };
};

template <>
class A<void>
{
  void f();
  struct some_type_helper;
};

struct A<void>::some_type_helper
{
  typedef decltype(std::bind(&A::f, std::declval<A>())) some_type;
};
```

Comment: Yes, such encapsulation can be useful sometimes. Still, in this case I think using std::declval<A *> as Johannes suggested is easier and works nice as well.