# Template specialization failure while using decltype in template type

Tags: c++, c++20, template-specialization, decltype

I defined the following template structure:

```
template<typename T>  struct somestruct {};
```

and now the following specializations:

```
template<typename T> struct somestruct <std::vector<T>>                {};  // OK
template<typename T> struct somestruct <decltype(std::vector<T>  {})>  {};  // KO
```

However, the last specialization doesn't compile with the following error (see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/a1qEGahda)):

```
error: template parameters not deducible in partial specialization:
```

Naively, I would say that the two specializations are not so different, like the following seems to say:

```
template<typename T> void test ()  
{ 
    static_assert (std::is_same_v<std::vector<T>, decltype(std::vector<T>{})> );
}
```

**Question:** what is the technical reason that makes the compiler fail with the second specialization ? And is there a way to fix it (I mean my code, not the compiler) ?

There is an [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061740/decltype-in-class-template-specialization) that seems to be similar but maybe things/compiler/c++ may have changed.

Comment: what do you want to "fix"? Without the `decltype` it works as expected, no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because template argument deduction can't work due to [non deduced context](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts).

> If a template parameter is used only in non-deduced contexts and is
> not explicitly specified, template argument deduction fails.
>
> 3. The expression of a decltype-specifier:
>
>    ```
>    template<typename T>
>    void f(decltype(*std::declval<T>()) arg);
>
>    int n;
>    f<int*>(n); // P = decltype(*declval<T>()), A = int: T is in non-deduced context
>    ```

The 2nd code snippet is not exactly the same because template argument deduction isn't involved.